# How to change the Shell of Android

Tags: android

I am asking this question because , there are too many commands that are not working in Android.

like, who / which / find ( special what I want )

Comment: you working in android's device terminal??

Comment: @Shiv , yes I am working in android device terminal

Answer (score 2):

Find the source code of these commands, compile them with the cross compile toolchain. And push the binary file into the target device.

Generally those command are under `/system/bin` folder.

A better approach is to put the source into the Android source code, then after you compile the Android image, the generated system.img will contain what you want.

Under `/system/core/toolbox` in Android Source code, there are tools that already included in AOSP.

```
$ ls
alarm.c     cmp.c   dmesg.c       getevent.c   id.c        kill.c         lsof.c              mv.c           printenv.c  restorecon.c  runcon.c      setprop.c    sync.c     uptime.c
Android.mk  cp      du.c          getevent.h   ifconfig.c  ln.c           lsusb.c             nandread.c     ps.c        rm.c          schedtop.c    setsebool.c  syren.c    vmstat.c
cat.c       date.c  dynarray.c    getprop.c    iftop.c     load_policy.c  md5.c               netstat.c      r.c         rmdir.c       sendevent.c   sleep.c      toolbox.c  watchprops.c
chcon.c     dd.c    dynarray.h    getsebool.c  insmod.c    log.c          mkdir.c             newfs_msdos.c  readtty.c   rmmod.c       setconsole.c  smd.c        top.c      wipe.c
chmod.c     dd.h    exists.c      grep         ioctl.c     ls.c           MODULE_LICENSE_BSD  NOTICE         reboot.c    rotatefb.c    setenforce.c  start.c      touch.c
chown.c     df.c    getenforce.c  hd.c         ionice.c    lsmod.c        mount.c             notify.c       renice.c    route.c       setkey.c      stop.c       umount.c
```

After you add your .c file like who.c, find.c, Don't forget to modify the Android.mk.